# Find username on network and show location

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to type in a persons name or network username, and have it tell me the computer ip and/or computer name they are logged into using command line or powershell. Is this possible?

Comment: What if they're logged onto more than one computer?

Comment: I am not sure. I was just wondering if such a command exists.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes it is possible, but no simple one line PowerShell command to do it.

Here are a few possible solutions:

- One solution, that is not practical in large organizations, is to use WMI to connect to every machine on the network and pull the currently logged on user. (Don't do this)
- Another solution is to have a log on script that, at log on, writes to a database the username, and current machine name, that the user is logged on to. Then, at log off, remove the entry from the database. (this can be done relatively easily)
- Another solution that we actually have implemented in my organization, is to use the Computer's "Managed By" field in Active Directory. We have a script that at log on, writes the username to the *Managed By* field. Then using PowerShell, it is a simple one line Active Directory query to find the machines that they are logged onto:

`Get-ADComputer -Filter {ManagedBy -eq "userName"}`

See: [Find Out What Computer a User Logged Into](http://deployhappiness.com/find-out-what-computer-a-user-logged-into/) for more information.

Comment: Ah so it's possible using what you have above to pull things from AD? I can use this right now?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You just need to add a GPO to run a logon/off script that updates the Managed By field. I updated the answer with a link on how to do it. See: http://deployhappiness.com/find-out-what-computer-a-user-logged-into/

Comment: Logoff solution needs to be thought through more as blue screens / other fatals like sudden power / network loss may prevent the script from executing as expected.